# How to acces to other property value by object id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I've almost finished building my OneToMany CRUD MEAN application but I have one problem.

I have two collections in my database

Games:

```
{ "_id" : 1, 
"title" : "Prey", 
"developer" : "Arkane Studios", 
"publisherId" : 1, 
"year" : 2017, 
"gerne" : "Action" }
```

and Publishers:

```
{ "_id" : 1, 
"name" : "Bethesda Softworks" }
```

In my game details html file I have this:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="form-control">Title: {{ game.title }}</label>
     <label class="form-control">Developer: {{ game.developer}}</label>
     <label class="form-control">Publiser: {{ game.publisherId }}</label>
     <label class="form-control">Year: {{ game.year }}</label>
     <label class="form-control">Gerne: {{ game.gerne }}</label>
     <label class="form-control">ID: {{ game._id }}</label>
    <a href="#/games" class="btn btn-default"> Back</a>
```

Is there any way to show publisher name instead of its _id?

Comment: Do you use Mongoose or ordinary MongoDB?

Comment: I use Mongoose.

Comment: You can use Mongoose's [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$lookup` aggregate function to do left outer join `games` collection with `publishers` in `Mongoose` to get the publisher documents embedded with the games document if exists.

You can use the publisher fields embedded in games to populate in UI

publishers

```
> db.publishers.find({_id:1}).pretty()
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Bethesda Softworks" }
```

games

```
> db.games.find({_id:1}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "title" : "Prey",
    "developer" : "Arkane Studios",
    "publisherId" : 1,
    "year" : 2017,
    "gerne" : "Action"
}
```

$lookup

```
> db.games.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $lookup:
                {
                    from : "publishers", 
                    localField:"publisherId", 
                    foreignField:"_id", 
                    as : "publisher"
                }
        }
    ]
).pretty()
```

output

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "title" : "Prey",
    "developer" : "Arkane Studios",
    "publisherId" : 1,
    "year" : 2017,
    "gerne" : "Action",
    "publisher" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "Bethesda Softworks"
        }
    ]
}
>
```